# Cake -Experimental Switch Compile Error

Tags: c#, roslyn, cakebuild

I am trying to use the Cake-Plist addin and received an error that dynamic is not yet implemented in the version of Roslyn that was being used.  Then from advise for someone else I was told to try the -Experimental switch.  When using the switch I am receiving the following error when it is trying to compile the build script.

```
Error: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException: (2,1): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.CompilationError(DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.GetExecutor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.Run(Object globals)
    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.Run(Object globals)
    at Cake.Scripting.Roslyn.Nightly.DefaultRoslynNightlyScriptSession.Execute(Script script)
    at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptRunner.Run(IScriptHost host, FilePath scriptPath, IDictionary`2 arguments)
    at Cake.Commands.BuildCommand.Execute(CakeOptions options)
    at Cake.CakeApplication.Run(CakeOptions options)
    at Cake.Program.Main()
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: Sounds like you need to compile against a later version of the framework (which includes that method)

Comment: Maybe you're missing a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference needs to be added to Microsoft.CSharp.dll.

```
#reference "Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
```

https://gitter.im/cake-build/cake?at=57add5a3364ad7fc5acdb660

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when running it on a Mac (OSX El Capitan).

I couldn't find the `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` anywhere on the Mac (other than in my MS Windows installation), and didn't want to add it as a dependency into one of my projects just for the sake of getting it to build like this on a mac.

I noticed, however, that `Mono.CSharp.dll` was being downloaded into the `./tools/Cake` folder. This serves roughly the same purpose, so I tried to reference it with

`#r "Mono.CSharp.dll"`

That didn't work either. But when I changed it to

`#r "./tools/Cake/Mono.CSharp.dll"`

It worked perfectly.

Now all I need to do is determine which platform it's running on and use the correct

`#r "xxx.CSharp.dll"`...

Comment: Did you solve referencing different assemblies on different platforms? I'm at the same point.

Comment: ugh no, I got sidetracked and actually never got back to it. sorry :(

Comment: OK, thanks @wilson. I got a solution that worked for me and have written it up as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260186/1386540

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection instead of dynamic.  A little less elegant but avoids [issues referencing `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` and `Mono.CSharp.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41454852/1386540).

[The example](http://cake-contrib.github.io/Cake.Plist/docs/usage/examples) would be written as follows.

```
#addin "Cake.Plist"

Task("update-ios-version")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        var plist = File("./src/Demo/Info.plist");
        var data = DeserializePlist(plist);

        var itemPropertyInfo = data.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
        itemPropertyInfo.SetValue(data, gitVersion.AssemblySemVer, new[] { "CFBundleShortVersionString" });
        itemPropertyInfo.SetValue(data, gitVersion.FullSemVer, new[] { "CFBundleVersion" });

        SerializePlist(plist, data);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on track to solve my issue. `var plist = File(project.Path.GetDirectory() + "/info.plist");` `var data = (Dictionary<string, object>) DeserializePlist(plist);`
`var bundleId = data["CFBundleIdentifier"].ToString();`